# sudo apt update is interrupted by 403 error in ubuntu

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, terminal

I'm trying to update my repository and I keep getting an error from docker and I don't know how to fix it.

Error:

```
Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  
403  Forbidden [IP: 2600:9000:2251:e800:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
 E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
 N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
 N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm assuming I have to add the InRelease file to docker manually but I need guidance since I'm completely new to ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the official GPG key following the [official docker installation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) on ubuntu?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Assuming you are on a x86_64/amd64 system, execute:

```
 echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

I recommend you to follow that guide instead of installing by apt.

Comment: thank you for responding, this is what i get when i request the keyring:  The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Are you running in WSL? Can you simply `curl https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg` ? How did you install Docker?

Comment: I simply installed it using apt-get and then removed it to try the method you've shown me. i'm running this version: "5.11.0-36-generic"

Comment: Try to [uninstall completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker)  Docker following the steps on there and reinstall following the steps on the official guide. If a clean install fails we will check another things. If you execute `curl https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg` what is the output?

Comment: @Lazlo did you manage to get it working?

Comment: I did, thank you Juan, you've been a great help!! much appreciated.

Comment: @Lazlo great! At the end, the problem was that you lacked the GPG key when installing Docker, for so I ever recommend to follow the official install guide instead of just install by apt, I'm glad you managed it to work, don't forget to accept as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score -2):

Hey I am getting the same error and fixed by manaually downloading the deb files from the dist related to my own instaltion here hope this helps:
[enter link description here](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/pool/stable/amd64/)